# how to read the json with data like and process using objectMapper in java

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, parsing

i have json string as below being streamed from kakfa topic {“card_id”:348702330256514,“member_id”:37495066290,“amount”:4380912,“postcode”:96774,“pos_id”:248063406800722,“transaction_dt”:“01-03-2018 08:24:29”}

How to parse this data using ObjectMapper with TransactionData.class and read values using getters and setters.

```
 rdd.foreach(a -> { System.out.println(a);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

 TransactionData cardTransactions = 
 mapper.readValue(a,TransactionData.class);
 System.out.println(cardTransactions);
                    TransactionData transData = new TransactionData();

                    JSONObject obj = new 
JSONObject(cardTransactions.toString());

                    String cardId = obj.get(“card_id”).toString();
                    System.out.println(“Printing json cardId: “+ cardId);
                    transData.setCard_id(cardId);

                    String memberId = obj.get(“member_id”).toString();
        System.out.println(“Printing json memberId: “+ memberId);
                    transData.setMember_id(memberId);

                    int amount = obj.getInt(“amount”);
                    System.out.println(“Printing json Amount: “+ amount);
                    transData.setAmount(amount);

                    int postcode = obj.getInt(“postcode”);
     System.out.println(“Printing json Postcode: “+ postcode);
                    transData.setPostcode(postcode);

                    String pos_id = obj.get(“pos_id”).toString();
                    System.out.println(“Printing json pos_id: “+ pos_id);
                    transData.setPos_id(pos_id);

      String transaction_dt = obj.getString(“transaction_dt”);
   System.out.println(“Printing json transaction_dt: “+ transaction_dt);
                    transData.setTransaction_dt(transaction_dt);
                    transData.setUid(cardId + “#” + amount);
   System.out.println(“Printing json transaction_dt: “+ transData.getTransaction_dt());

                });
```

Comment: Could you add more details, what would like to achieve?
read messages from Kafka in Spark and parse them to instance of some class (ex. TransactionData)?

Comment: after fetching those values i have a lookup table in hbase in which i will check if the card details already exists to determine if transaction incoming is genuine/fraud then based the status i have update corresponding tables in hbase again. so for that i have a separate code called HbaseDAO.getTxnDetails() in which i manage my hbase funcationality i would like to know to use object Mapper and achieve this. Hope i provided details as requested if not let me know.

Comment: also i have the class TransactionData with all the columns declared with getters and setters defined once i parse i should be able to pass this data to HbaseDAO class where i will do the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code with below imports:

```
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<TransactionData> dataList = new ArrayList<TransactionData>();

rdd.foreach(a -> {
        try
           {
             // Use this line if the incoming data is an exact match
             // Map<TransactionData> transData = mapper.readValue(a, new TypeReference<TransactionData>(){});

             // Else the following code
             Map<String, Object> mapList = mapper.readValue(a, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
             TransactionData transData = new TransactionData();
             for(Map<String,Object> map : mapList)
             {
                transData.setCard_id(map.get("card_id").toString());
                // add others..........
             }
                dataList.add(transData);
            }
    }
catch (JsonParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (JsonMappingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } });
```

If you need to create a dataframe:

```
Dataset<Row> dff = spark.createDataFrame(dataList, TransactionData.class);
```